# C ternary conditional operator to MIPS assembly with one side loaded from memory

Tags: c, assembly, mips

C statement

```
A= A? C[0] : B;
```

Is is correct to write in  assembly instruction this way?
Assuming `$t1=A, $t2=B, $s1=base` address of Array C:

```
         beq   $t1, $0,  ELSE
         lw    $t1, 0($s1)
ELSE:    add   $t1, $t2, $0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't seem correct because `add   $t1, $t2, $0` will be executed even if `$t1 != $0`.

I hope that this works (not tested):

```
         beq   $t1, $0,  ELSE
         sll $0, $0, 0 # NOP : avoid the instruction after branch being executed
         lw    $t1, 0($s1)
         j END
         sll $0, $0, 0 # NOP : avoid the instruction after branch being executed
ELSE:    add   $t1, $t2, $0
END:
```

This code assumes that the elements of `C` are 4-byte long each.

Comment: Thak you very much! May you explain why there is a need for NOP?

Comment: MIPS has a delay slot following branches and jumps that always gets executed. If you are using a simulator (e.g. `MARS` or `spim`) you made need to turn on this behaviour. Otherwise you can presumably ignore it considering I assume you are doing schoolwork.

Comment: @KonradLindenbach: You don't need to enable branch-delay slots for this code to work correctly, exactly *because* the delay slot is filled with a NOP instead of an instruction that needs to be executed (like putting the LW in the delay slot for `j END`).  And BTW, Mike: I think a NOP using `addu` or `or` would reduce the risk of bottlenecking on ALU port throughput on a superscalar MIPS that can't shift on as many ports as it can do simple ALU ops on.  (Barrel shifters are expensive to build and in less demand than adders or boolean units.)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid an unconditional `j`.  Instead of structuring this as an if/else, always do the A=B (because copying a register is cheaper than jumping) and then optionally do the load.

On a **MIPS with branch-delay slots**, the delay slot actually *helps* us:

```
# $t1=A, $t2=B, $s1=base
    beq   $t1, $zero,  noload
    move  $t1, $t2                  # branch delay: runs always

    lw    $t1, 0($s1)
noload:
    # A= A? C[0] : B;
```

On a **MIPS *without* branch-delay slots** (like MARS or SPIM in their default config):

```
# MIPS without branch-delay slots
# $t1=A, $t2=B, $s1=base
    move  $t3, $t1              # tmp=A
    move  $t1, $t2              # A=B
    beq   $t3, $zero,  noload   # test the original A

    lw    $t1, 0($s1)
noload:
    # $t1 =   A= A ? C[0] : B;
```

**If we can clobber B and rearrange registers, we can save an insn without a branch-delay**:

```
# MIPS without branch-delay slots
# $t1=A, $t2=B, $s1=base
    beq   $t1, $zero,  noload

    lw    $t2, 0($s1)
noload:
    # $t2 = A.   B is "dead": we no longer have it in a register
```

A `move $t3, $t2` before the BEQ could save B in another register before this sequence.  Ending up with your variables in different registers can save instructions, but makes it harder to keep track of things.  In a loop, you can get away with this if you're unrolling the loop because the 2nd copy of the code can re-shuffle to get registers back the way they need to be for the top of the loop.

`move x, y` is a pseudo-instruction for `or x, y, $zero` or `ori x, y, 0`.  Or `addu x, y, $zero`.  Implement it however you like or let your assembler do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Write a MIPS segment  for the C statement

```
x=5;  y=7; 

Land(x,y,z)   //  z=x &y    as procedure call

if (z>x) y=x+1
```